# Multiprocessing: AttributeError: 'Imported' object has no attribute '__private_method'

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pickle

I faced with this problem in my work code, so I can't show it. But I wrote some short example, which exactly reproduce error and cuts off redundant logic.

Example have two files: `Example.py` & `ImportedExample.py`.

**Example.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from ImportedExample import Imported

class Example:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.imported = Imported(number)

def func(example: Example):
    print(example)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ex = Example(3)

    p = Process(target=func, args=(ex,))
    p.start()
```

**ImportedExample.py**

```
class Imported:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        self.ref = self.__private_method

    def __private_method(self):
        print(self.number)
```

And Traceback looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File"C:\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main 
exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: 'Imported' object has no attribute '__private_method'
```

The main detail is that when I make `__private_method()` non-private (renaming to `private_method()`), all works fine.

I don't understand why this happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: There seems to be some issues with pickling.

Comment: Thanks to @pacholik for detailed answer. His explanation cleared everething up for me and his suggestion solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing` module uses `pickle` for transferring object between processes.

For an object to be *pickable*, it has to be accessible by name. Thanks to [private name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers), referenced private methods don’t fall in that category.

I suggest making the method *protected* – that is naming the method with only one leading underscore. From a global point of view, protected methods shoud be treated just as private methods, but they are not subject of name mangling.